# *Why* is Bombieri-Pila uniform?

Tags: algebraic-curves, diophantine-equations, diophantine-geometry

I am about to give a couple of lectures on Bombieri-Pila/the determinant method. Bombieri-Pila gives a bound $$|C(\mathbb{Q}) \cap B \cap \mathbb{Z}^2| \ll_{d,\epsilon} N^{1/d+\epsilon}$$ for $C$ a plane curve of degree $d$ and $B$ a square of side $N$. In particular, it is a bound that (like the older bound by Jarnik (1926), and newer bounds using the same basic idea) is uniform, i.e., does not depend on the coefficients of $f$.

In Bombieri-Pila's paper, as (if I remember correctly) in Jarnik's, obtaining a uniform bound actually takes a bit of work; the way I see it, one has to show that, if a higher derivative of $f$ is too large for the main argument to function, the conclusion is true for other reasons. Is there a more immediate, easily explicable reason why the end bound should be uniform?

(Note: if one proceeds $p$-adically, the fact that the method gives a uniform bound is much clearer. I am asking a question about the original, archimedean method, not about $p$-adic variants.)

Comment: I do not remember it well, but possibly we use the following property of the curve of degree d: a Vandermonde type determinant of enough many points on the curve equals to 0? This property does not depend on coefficients at all.

Comment: You still need the coefficients, though. The point is that, under some conditions on the coefficients, the determinant has absolute value less than 1, and hence, since it is an integer, it equals 0.

Comment: Hm, but there is a determinant, which is zero always-always (even if the coefficients are irrational and so on)? Say, if the points lie on a conic, it means that the determinant $[1,x_i,y_i,x_iy_i,x_i^2,y_i^2],i=1,\ldots,6$ is zero for any 6 points $(x_i,y_i)$ on the curve. Does not this help to estimate the number of points?

Comment: (Where and when are said lectures? :) Perhaps I’ve misunderstood something but, and I admit this is the least satisfying possible answer (since it doesn’t truly answer “why”), the argument is iterable (and of course they iterate it on the bad subintervals) and the tiny dependence left over after this iteration is eaten by the N^{o(1)}. I’m guessing you want a legitimate answer as to why, e.g. that in the higher genus case the number of points should be <<_d 1!)